# Can't change Status Bar Color in Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to change my status bar color and it's not working.

I've tried with StatusBar directly from native cordova, and later I've tried with $cordovaStatusbar plugin.
Both cases I tested on my device (LG G3 - Android 5.0) and it's NOT WORK =(.

I tested on simulator (Genymotion) in versions above 5.0, and it's work.

Is this normal?

My currently code is, in app.run()

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }

    if (window.StatusBar) {

        if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            //StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#60C7CC");
            $cordovaStatusbar.styleHex('#60C7CC');
        } else {
            StatusBar.styleLightContent();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Try to add an `alert("I'm android");` in your `if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {` and check the result in your device.

Comment: The android skd has to be at least on 21 level according to [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/blob/master/src/android/StatusBar.java) code at the method setStatusBarBackgroundColor. What sdk is available on your LG?

Comment: I have your answer. Please answer the following questions in you post. Is this your first app? What is your target platform? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001)?  After this reply here, so I know you update your post.

Comment: Hello JesseMonroy650, I'm using CLI and currently my target is Android. I'm developing the app using Ionic Framework.